# VBA Excel - Date Formatting Iteration Issue

Tags: excel, vba, iteration, date-format

Basically, I want VBA to loop through a range (E2 - last row), and when it finds any month and day "dd/mm" to add on 2014, c.i.p "dd/mm/2014." Secondly, if it finds "n/a" it should highlight that cell in red. My code doesn't do anything, however. What is wrong with my code?

```
Sub yearstandard()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim range As range

    Dim i As Long


    LastRow = FindLastRow(1)

    For i = 5 To LastRow        'test row 1 to whatever the last populated row is

    Set cell = Cells(i, 2)  'Define cell as the cell to be tested e.g. (cells 1,1) is A1

    Select Case cell.Value      'select case value in cell

    Case Is = "dd/mm"

    cell.Value = "dd/mm/2014"       'wrap each date entered in year 2014

    Case Is = "n/a"

        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)    'highlight cells with value "n/a" in red

    End Select

    Next i      'go to the next loop counter


End Sub
```

Comment: Did your code compiled? I mean, does it work with `Case Is`? because is the first time I see this thing

Comment: No, it did not compile. However, I have used Case Is with a utility than altered cells in a range based on their values, and that one did compile. I am new to VBA and programming in general, so if there is a better way to write this utility I am all ears. Also, I'm wondering if "dd/mm" is the correct code to interpret a date, e.g. 3/14.

Comment: @Peter.Ward Your code is searching for the string **"dd/mm"** in the cell.  It is not going to find an actual day and month.  You need to provide a **better explanation and examples of your data**.  And if you have entered a date in the format of **dd/mm**, it will not be stored that way in the cell.  Also, are you really looking for the string **"n/a"** in the cell?  Or are you looking for the error **#N/A**?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'm working with a very simple spreadsheet that has two fields: names and dates. The name field is populated, but I am going to manually enter the date field. I'm fine with entering, for example, 3/14, but I want to automate the addition of 2014 to any month and day entered, e.g. 3/14 --> 3/14/2014. Some records, however, don't have a date, so in those cases I would enter n/a. I would like the cell to automatically highlight red for these instances.

Comment: @Peter.Ward Response is in my Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you indicated you would be manually entering either 3/14 or n/a into cells.

Assuming your regional settings are US (mdy), and you are going to be entering the data this year, there is no need for VBA.  Merely enter 3/14 and Excel will automatically add the current year.  With regard to turning the n/a red, just use conditional formatting on the entire column.  You might want to custom format the column as d/m/yyyy if you don't "see" the 2014.

If you absolutely must do this in VBA, then something like the below will set those options for range in column E from E2 to the last row.

I have also assumed that there is no other conditional formatting in that column.  If there is, then, instead of deleting the old conditional formatting, we will need to preserve it when running the macro.

```
Sub FormatColE()
With Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""n/a"""
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With
End Sub
```